KubeDB provisioner and azure workload identity
So KubeDB provisioner is responsible to pull images from the registry. In our AKS cluster this would be our private registry, which is configured to only accept Azure Active Directory authentication - one cannot use user/password authentication.
So we setup federated identity credentials for the namespace service account and we have the respective Azure AD Identity associated with it. The framework that allows this is Azure Workload Identity.
Assuming the federated identity credentials and the azure identity itself already exist, the following steps must be taken to enable it for the KubeDB provisioner pod:

The KubeDB provisioner pod must have the label azure.workload.identity/use: "true"
The KubeDB namespace service account must have the name recorded in the federated identity credentials subject
The KubeDB namespace service account must have the annotation azure.workload.identity/client-id: <azure identity client id>

Now, the service account name is not an issue - we can create the federated identity credentials with any name as needed. Custom annotation is not a problem either, since the kubedb-provisioner chart allows to customize annotations.
The problem is the custom label. It seems that KubeDB charts make a deliberate decision NOT to allow custom labels on the objects they create.
I am sure there is some K8s best practice behind it, but what can be done when it is absolutely necessary to add a label to a KubeDB pod?
To complicate things a little bit more, we deploy all the apps using ArgoCD. So if I use some kind of out-of-band "labeller" (do not know if that exists at all) it would be at odds with ArgoCD. I will have to instruct the latter to ignore the differences in labels, which is doable, but not ideal.
My question - what is the best way to add custom labels to the KubeDB pods given that their helm charts do not support it and that we use ArgoCD to deploy it? (Besides creating a fork, that is).
EDIT 1
The KubeDB charts - https://github.com/kubedb/installer/tree/v2024.8.21/charts
I am not hooked on KubeDB. I need it for Redis. So advice on alternative Redis operators is welcome as well.

Can you once read this- https://mycloudjourney.medium.com/what-is-mutatingwebhook-in-kubernetes-a62f79598ecb . As a workaround, the Kubernetes Mutating Admission Webhook will allow you to automatically inject labels, annotations, or other configurations into Kubernetes objects when they are created or updated. This can be used for adding the necessary azure.workload.identity/use: "true" label to KubeDB pods.

Another option is ArgoCD supports the use of Sync Hooks to perform custom actions before or after a sync operation. You can use a Sync Hook to apply a kubectl patch command to add the necessary labels after the KubeDB pods are deployed. https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide/sync-waves/#hooks

As I mentioned in comments, there are few ways to get this done.  One of them being Kubernetes Mutating Admission Webhook allows you to automatically inject labels, annotations, or other configurations into Kubernetes objects when they are created or updated.
webhooks require HTTPS, so you need a certificate.
openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout webhook-server.key -x509 -days 365 -out webhook-server.crt -subj "/CN=webhook-server.webhook-system.svc"

followed by a secret to store the TLS Certificate and Key
kubectl -n webhook-system create secret tls webhook-server-tls --cert=webhook-server.crt --key=webhook-server.key


Deploy the Mutating Webhook Server (I am using a simple Python-based webhook server that adds the azure.workload.identity/use: "true" label to KubeDB pods)
deployment for the same-
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mutating-webhook
  namespace: webhook-system
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mutating-webhook
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mutating-webhook
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mutating-webhook
        image: ghcr.io/open-policy-agent/opa:0.40.0
        args:
          - "run"
          - "--server"
          - "--addr=0.0.0.0:443"
          - "--tls-cert-file=/certs/webhook-server.crt"
          - "--tls-private-key-file=/certs/webhook-server.key"
        volumeMounts:
          - name: certs
            mountPath: "/certs"
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: certs
        secret:
          secretName: webhook-server-tls

Service for the Webhook
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mutating-webhook
  namespace: webhook-system
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 443
    targetPort: 443
  selector:
    app: mutating-webhook


and finally create the MutatingWebhookConfiguration that tells k8s to call your webhook server when a KubeDB pod is created.
apiVersion: admissionregistration.k8s.io/v1
kind: MutatingWebhookConfiguration
metadata:
  name: mutating-webhook-configuration
webhooks:
  - name: mutating-webhook.webhook-system.svc
    clientConfig:
      service:
        name: mutating-webhook
        namespace: webhook-system
        path: "/mutate"
      caBundle: <BASE64_ENCODED_CA_CERT>
    rules:
      - operations: ["CREATE"]
        apiGroups: [""]
        apiVersions: ["v1"]
        resources: ["pods"]
        scope: "Namespaced"
    failurePolicy: Fail
    admissionReviewVersions: ["v1"]
    matchPolicy: Equivalent
    objectSelector:
      matchExpressions:
        - key: app.kubernetes.io/name
          operator: In
          values: ["kubedb-provisioner"]
    namespaceSelector:
      matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/metadata.name
          operator: In
          values: ["default"]
    sideEffects: None


This CaBundle value you will get if you do-
cat webhook-server.crt | base64 | tr -d '\n'


Now we have the Mutating Admission Webhook configured, just need to ensure that the webhook server logic is correctly implemented to handle the mutation.
For example if we use a python server that mutates incoming pod creation requests by adding the azure.workload.identity/use: "true" label and in order to use the same inside our k8s cluster we can create a dockerfile image from the same
FROM python:3.9-slim

RUN pip install Flask

COPY webhook.py /app/webhook.py
COPY webhook-server.crt /certs/webhook-server.crt
COPY webhook-server.key /certs/webhook-server.key

WORKDIR /app

CMD ["python", "webhook.py"]



and update the mutating-webhook-deployment.yaml with that image

Reference-
Official K8s doc on Mutating webhook
Example on mutating webhook

+1 for the detailed answer and I will accept it. I do know what mutating webhooks are, but I was hoping there was something I missed in the KubeDB setup. I think I would rather ditch KubeDB in favor of KubeBlocks, because I do not like the idea of starting to use a framework by writing a custom mutating webhook to workaround the framework's rigid approach to custom labels. But the answer is helpful in general, so thank you.
